# .htaccess - Prevent direct subdomain access

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a subdomain which i need to disable access too(give a 404).
Example;  [abcd.domain.com] - when this url is accessed, the user should receive a 404Page not found.
I have managed to get this working with the code below, BUT, however, its also giving me a 404Page not found EVEN when i browse to [abcd.com] 
How could this be modified so it would work both ways?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abcd.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `[OR]` in your conditions.

Simplified rule should be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abcd\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. 
I actually noticed my first code that i posted is working both ways. BUT only for one of my domains. Its very strange! I've cleared my cache, tried different browsers, accessed from different IP. but whether abcd.com OR abcd.domain.com i get a 404. (except for one of my domains)
Would you or anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! it is working, Partly. Its blocking [abcd.domain.com] and allowing [abcd.com],[www.abcd.com] as expected BUT [WWW.abcd.domain.com] is NOT being blocked.

Comment: Yup! Thats the one! Its working as should.
I cannot thank you enough! Thank you, thank you, thank you!
Have a FANTASTIC day!

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.